# Is there a method available for UWP apps to get available disk space

Tags: c++, uwp

I am working on a UWP app that depends on available storage space, and would like to have that information prior to a save fail.  I have tried the RetrievePropertiesAsync calls on the known folders, but do not get a Freespace or Capacity property in the resultant list.  Is there a method available for this?

Code used to access properties:

```
auto basicProperties = co_await videosFolder->GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
auto retrievedProperties = co_await basicProperties->RetrievePropertiesAsync(propertiesToRetrieve);
unsigned long freeSpace = retrievedProperties->Size;
auto it = retrievedProperties->First();
bool validData = (it != nullptr);
while (validData)
{
    String^ text = it->Current->Key;
    validData = it->MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: GetDiskFreeSpace info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364935(v=vs.85).aspx says it support  Windows Store apps

Comment: Works Great!  Thanks

Comment: Can you post it as answer, so we can mark the question as answered? Thanks!