# Windows IoT Raspberry Pi 3 C# GetDiskFreeSpace

Tags: c#, storage, raspberry-pi3, usb-drive, windows-iot-core-10

I have a USB thumb-drive connected to my raspberry pi 3. I'd need to find out how to check for the available disk space to be printed on a textblock. I couldn't find any example for UWP application. 
What I found was [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Is there a method available for UWP apps to get available disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056945/is-there-a-method-available-for-uwp-apps-to-get-available-disk-space)
Is there any example I could refer to?
Thanks.

Updated: 
I have tried [[Get available disk free space for a given path on Windows [duplicate]]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14465265/8603417) .. Couldn't get it to work too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use StorageFolder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync() API to get the free space size of USB storage.I tested with the following pieces of code:

```
            var removableDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
            var externalDevices = await removableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
            var usbDriver = externalDevices.FirstOrDefault();

            var allProperties = usbDriver.Properties;
            IEnumerable<string> propertiesToRetrieve = new List<string> { "System.FreeSpace" };

            var storageIdProperties = await allProperties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(propertiesToRetrieve);

            var freeSpaceSize = storageIdProperties["System.FreeSpace"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any method to convert the bytes to GB?

Comment: You need to create a function for that.Please reference the rule of converting Byte to Gigabyte:
https://www.unitconverters.net/data-storage/gigabyte-to-byte.htm